# Is there a way shortcut type bounds in Scala?

Tags: scala

When defining a covariant class, all the method declarations need to contain something along the lines of:

```
[B >: A] //A is the main type variable
```

Is there a way to declare something at the class level that makes B available so I don't need to repeat this in every method?

I tried everything I could think of using `type`, but nothing would compile.

Comment: I can't answer because I don't enough Scala, but you might try to define a macro (and/or annotations).

Comment: I'll look into that. I haven't gotten into macros yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it is possible.

```
class Test[+A] {
    type B >: A
    def doStuff(b : B): B = ...
}
```

I thought that there would be a `=` in there somewhere.

Note: I haven't tested it thoroughly. It appears to work the same, but I don't know for sure.